# How to display image in web application using Ember .js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js

Please forgive if this question is too silly or asked before I goggled a lot but I didn't get the right answer.
I'm new to **Ember.js** and I'm stuck with a problem I need to display my avatar pic in a image box like

```
<img src="~/Assets/Images/avatary.png" alt="avatar">
```

My question is How can I do the same using Ember.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an image wrapper to have ember handle bindings and more for you.
For example you could create something like this:

```
App.AvatarImage = Ember.View.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['src', 'alt'],
  src: '~/Assets/Images/avatary.png', // note that this path will not work at all if you serve your ember app from an webserver
  alt: 'avatar',
  tagName: 'img'
});
```

And then use it in your templates like so:

```
{{view App.AvatarImage}}
```

Here a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eloyof/2/edit)

Hope it helps

Comment: How do you upload an image using jQuery and show it back to the user in a view?

Comment: @Amaan, posting a question tagged `ember.js` would be more appropriate I guess :)